# Unity shader graph slow

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, shader-graph

**Unity 2020.3.12f1**

**HDRP**

Whenever I add a single node in Shader Graph, the progress bar "compiling shader" takes around 20 seconds to complete. Multiply that by dozens of nodes and we're talking a very long time.

[image]

**Is there any way to speed this up?** It's a bit of a turn off when fiddling with shaders. I *almost* want to avoid using shaders because of this.

I'm running Windows 10 on a ~4Ghz 8-core CPU with 32G RAM and a 2080Ti graphics card.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?
Same here, and I might be wrong, but I kinda remember it to be much faster in previous versions.